# CMFCToolbar image disappears through remote desktop or when connected to projector

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using CMFCToolbar in my dialog derived from CDialog and loading the images on toolbar using LoadBitmap(). When I run the application, the images are visible properly. However, when I connect the computer through remote desktop, the images disappear. The same problem happens when computer remains idle for long time or goes to sleep mode. This happens only with CMFCToolbar. All other toolbars are visible properly.

After some debugging, I had below observation (though it is strange). I could find that whenever some exception (e.g. call SetWindowPos() on NULL pointer) occurs in OnSize() event (which is overloaded in my dialog) then the images don't disappear. It means windows stops further calls after exception and the issue does not occur. However, when there is no exception then OnSize() gets evaluated successfully and this issue appears. I tried removing OnSize() event but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could figure out and resolve the problem. I was loading a PNG image using LoadBitmap(). It was working perfectly fine until I connected to remote desktop or projector or the computer was awaken from sleep mode. When I replaced PNG file with BMP file, the issue got resolved. It seems that the PNG files don't work with CMFCToolbar control in these scenarios though they work in normal workflow.